# Use String.Replace in a Python for loop

Tags: python, string, replace

I want to use **string.replace** using for loop. This is my code:

```
new = ['p','q','r']
my_str = 'there are two much person a, person b, person c.'
old = ['a','b','c']

for i in range(0,len(old)):
    my_str = string.replace(my_str,old[i],new[i])

print(my_str)
```

But it is giving me error:

> TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Desired output:

> there are two much person p, person q, person r.

This is just an example, I want to run a for loop for 10,000 length list.

Comment: Can not reproduce. Your code runs fine on Python 2.7

Comment: The `string.replace` function has been deprecated for a very long time. You should use the`str.replace` method instead.

Comment: You know, even if you fix whatever weird problem you had, you're still going to replace the `a` in `are` and the `c` in `much`.

Comment: But it doesnt work for this example, I have written in answer part.

Comment: Perhaps, you can rewrite your program to use `.format`, something like: `new_str = 'there are two much person {}, person {}, person {}'.format(*new)`

Comment: Based on your update, which you've since deleted, the problem is the 'Y' in Years is caps, and in 'years' is lower case. Next time, post a [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
new = ['p','q','r']
my_str = 'there are two much person a, person b, person c.'
old = ['a','b','c']

for i in range(len(old)):
    my_str = my_str.replace(old[i],new[i])

print(my_str)
```

but that is propably not very fast

If entries in old are all letters-only you can do

```
import re

new = ['p','q','r']
my_str = 'there are two much person a, person b, person c.'
old = ['a','b','c']

word=re.compile(r"\w*") # word characters
old_new=dict(zip(old,new))
ong=old_new.get
my_str=word.sub((lambda s:ong(s,s)),my_str)

print(my_str)
```

this also avoids the double replacement problem if an entry is in both old and new (not avoided in the shorter solution)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I can not reproduce your problem; your code runs fine on Python 2.7. However, there are better ways to do it. First, instead of using a `range`, you could `zip` the `old` and `new` lists:

```
for i in range(0,len(old)):
    my_str = string.replace(my_str,old[i],new[i])
```

However, this will still replace the `a` in `are` and the `c` in `much`, and it might also replace characters that were introduced in an earlier replacement, which is probably not what you want. Instead, you could use the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module, joining the strings to be replaced with `|` to a regex and delimiting it with `\b` word boundary characters, e.g. `\b(a|b|c)\b` in your case, and use a dictionary to look up the proper replacements.

```
d = dict(zip(old, new))
p = r'\b(' + '|'.join(old) + r')\b'
my_str = re.sub(p, lambda m: d.get(m.group()), my_str)
```

Result: `there are two much person p, person q, person r.`

Comment: like my solution this only works if entries in old only consist of word-characters

Comment: `.join(old)` may not be a good idea if `len(old)` is 10000. OTOH, the OP may have an XY problem...

Comment: @PM2Ring Good point, in this light janbrohl's solution might work better. +1

Answer (score 1):

`string.replace()` is available on Python 2.x but deprecated in python 3.x.

Below is how you can use it in Python 3.x

> str.replace(old, new[, count])
>   Return a copy of the string with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new. If the optional argument count is given, only the first count occurrences are replaced.

In your case, it is `my_str.replace(old[index], new[index])`